# Is saying "_The_ invariant subspace" improper?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

It's just a question about semantics: does it make sense to refer to *the isomorphism between a given vector space and **the** invariant subspace of a endomorphism* or should I say *the isomorphism between a given vector space and **the maximal** invariant subspace of an endomorphism*?

Of course I know that invariant subspaces are subspaces of the maximal subspace, my question is whether in practice I need to specity *maximal*, or if it is implicit that "the" invariant subspace is the maximal one.

Comment: I'd say you should specify maximality the first time in a given text, and clarify that it will thereinafter be omitted.

Comment: I aggree with Cameron. Although, for example, it is quited common to see "The domain" of an unspecified function without ever having a reference that it is "the maximal possible domain", as usually subintended.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks to both of you; maybe Cameron you want to turn it as an answer?